# php ajax display data from database in multiple textboxes

Tags: php, jquery, html

Every one am new to php and ajax.
Am writing a code to fetch data from mysql database
and display them in textboxes but is not working.

Here is my code.
I need your help please.
Thanks in advance

```js
    $('#btn_get').on('click', function(){
     $.ajax({
       type    : "get",
       url     : '/path/to/php/file',       
       success : function(data)
       {
         $('#input-box1').val(data);
         $('#input-box2').val(data);
       }
     });
    });
```

```html
    <input type="text" id="input-box1">
     <input type="text" id="input-box2">
    <button type="button" id="btn_get">Click</button>
```

```php
    //get data from db here
    $textbox1 = 'foo';
    $textbox2 = 'deen';
    echo $textbox1;
    echo $textbox2;
```

Comment: `url     : '/path/to/php/file',`   **/path/to/php/file** must be the actual php file you requesting response from'

Answer (score 1):

Here are some approaches, maybe them can help you:

1. The first approach would be to check your console to make sure that the jQuery version allows you to use the **$.ajax()** resource. Some jQuery versions like the **"slim"** doesn't provide ajax calls.
2. Once you have checked that put the property **error** within your ajax call:

```
$('#btn_get').on('click', function(){
 $.ajax({
   type    : "get",
   url     : '/path/to/php/file',       
   success : function(data)
   {
     $('#input-box1').val(data);
     $('#input-box2').val(data);
   },
   error: function(xhr, ajaxOptions, thrownError) {
       console.log(xhr);
   }
 });
});
```

If you have a error response you will be able to identify it checking your browser's console tool (F12).

3. Check your **/path/to/php/file** to make sure that your file really exists.
4. Remember that the **success** callback gets your **echo** command as a string. So probably your return will be something like this:

```
foodeen
```

A good approach would be to return a json response:

```
$textbox1 = 'foo';
$textbox2 = 'deen';
echo json_encode(array($textbox1 ,"textBox1"));
```

Finally when your response is executed in the success callback you'll be able to convert it from plain string to a json format:

```
$('#btn_get').on('click', function(){
 $.ajax({
   type    : "get",
   url     : '/path/to/php/file',       
   success : function(data)
   {
     var response = JSON.stringify(data);
     $('#input-box1').val(response[0]);
     $('#input-box2').val(response[1]);
   },
   error: function(xhr, ajaxOptions, thrownError) {
       console.log(xhr);
   }
 });
});
```

Comment: I'm glad to hear that :)